# Get python object to return multiple values at creation time including self

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am parsing a text file and creating an object per line in the text file.
When parsing each line i create a time stamp that I want to be returned to the calling code together with object itself.

I realize and am currently doing it by storing the time stamp in the object itself and accessing it after creating the object but I find it more convenient for me if I could return self and the time stamp when creating the object.

Under I have a suggestion on how to do this, but I want to know if this is considered OK and if not, how can I do this properly?

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, infile):
        self.time_stamp = foobar(infile)
        self.line = barfoo(infile)

        return (self, self.time_stamp)

(obj, time_stamp) = Foo()
```

Cheers.

Comment: Use a factory function, not a constructor. Your code sample won't work, the return value of `__init__` is ignored I think.

Comment: There are no rules about this, only preference, and opinion. Some will say do it with method A some will say method B, some will also tell you not to do it at all. This question is not constructive to StackOverflow.

Comment: Personally, "accessing it after creating the object" would be the way I'd do this, it's the least error prone. (Although I also wouldn't have a data structure class "parse itself" from a file.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [can't return anything but `None` from `__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

> As a special constraint on constructors, no value may be returned; doing so will cause a TypeError to be raised at runtime.

Use a factory function:

```
def create_foo(infile):
    foo = Foo(infile)
    return foo, foo.time_stamp

...

obj, ts = create_foo(a_file)
```

or a [static method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
    @staticmethod:
    def create(infile):
        obj = Foo(infile)

        return obj, obj.time_stamp

...

obj, ts = Foo.create(a_file)
```

or, if you need it to work properly on subclasses, a [class method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod)

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, infile):
        obj = cls(infile)

        return obj, obj.time_stamp

...

obj, ts = Foo.create(a_file)
```

Of course, this is the simplest way:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, infile):
        self.time_stamp = ...


obj = Foo(a_file)
ts = obj.time_stamp
```

I don't think getting rid of this extra line warrants designing a factory.

Comment: When reading this I too realize this does not warrant any extra code. Thank you for the input.